# a4j:commandLink open a new tab after checking onComplete

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is there a way to use "oncomplete" from a4j:commandLink to open a new tab like "target" from h:commandLink ?
something like:

```
target="#{dashBoardBean.possuiDocumento ? '_blank' : '_self'}"


<a4j:commandLink action="#{dashBoardBean.visualizarDocumento}" 
                 oncomplete="#{dashBoardBean.possuiDocumento}">
</a4j:commandLink>
```

right now my code is like this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{dashBoardBean.visualizarDocumento}"
               target="#{uc.documento ? '_blank' : '_self'}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{uc}" target="#{dashBoardBean.contentTarget}" />
                <de:statusContent content="#{uc}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

now i need to make a check after the action and only then open the new tab, but h:commanLink doesn't have oncomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{dashBoardBean.visualizarDocumento}" update="@this" 
    oncomplete="window.open('yourNewPage.xhtml', '#{dashBoardBean.possuiDocumento ? '_blank' : '_self'}')">
</a4j:commandLink>
```